# Prevent objdump from truncating hex output

Tags: linux, binary, gnu, objdump

Using `objdump -dF` or just `objdump -d`, I experience that `objdump` truncates output:

```
0000000000400561 <.wm_split0> (File Offset: 0x561):
  400561:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
    ...

0000000000400565 <.end_0> (File Offset: 0x565):
```

Here it only displays two of the 4 bytes from position `0x400561` to `0x400565`.

I know the rest of the bytes are `0x00` in this case, but I have some tools that currently depends on four bytes being present.

How do I make `objdump` display hex for all addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `objdump` option when disassembling:

```
-z, --disassemble-zeroes       Do not skip blocks of zeroes when disassembling
```